# How to create perspective making a supermarket aisle. Illustrator CC

Tags: adobe-illustrator, creative-cloud, perspective

I am about to embark on recreating a supermarket aisle. There is perspective involved and I am wondering whether using the perspective grid is the best tool I have never used it before. I am also wondering whether to use the 3D and Materials e.g extrude and bevel to create a 3 dimensional effect for the products on the shelf. It seems quite daunting and maybe a bit beyond my skill level right now but am looking for the most effective way to do it. The illustration will be quite flat essentially no shading but there does need to be some perspective.

[image]

Comment: If the boxes, bottles, cans etc... on the shelves must look plausible like they could be for sale somewhere, the task as a 2D drawing job is colossal. In that case 3D modelling is the easiest way. Perspective and all different views of the items would be right in the image with zero effort. Shelves are easy to model. Common simple boxes, bottles and cans are as easy. The most difficult thing is to make or get otherwise legally usable images and texts on them. Illustrator's 3D is useless here, you need a program which can handle assemblies. Then you need only one copy of each product.

Comment: (continued) Your example has about 100 different products. I'm afraid you must radically simplify most of the package labels the keep the job profitable. 1...2 readable words (other than a story taken from a lorem ipsum -generator) and only in 10 nearest products may be the reasonable maximum. Creating a few simple items like this https://i.stack.imgur.com/Puqt7.png can be a fun, but making 100 of them is a tough job.

Comment: Thanks for the advice :). I am going to simplify not exactly copy it just the general idea that it can be registered as a supermarket shelf with products on it no words.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few ways this could be accomplished.

I, personally, hate the **** perspective grid. It's a cumbersome and annoying feature in my opinion.

There are, I'm sure, *thousands* of users that enjoy using the Perspective Grid and rely on it a great deal. In *no way* am I stating my method is "correct" or "right". It is merely one alternative to using Adobe's Perspective Grid.

I would.... draw each side of the aisle flat, then group and perspective distort the group. Then add depth manually (which would have to be done with or without using the Perspective Grid).

Once the depth is added, it's possible to perspective distort *again* to tweak the perspective if necessary.

[image]

One could ease the file complexity (and weight [kb]) by utilizing [**Symbols**](https://helpx.adobe.com/illustrator/using/symbols.html) for the products. Draw it once, create a symbol, and reuse the symbol will make for much smaller (and easier to manage) files.